# Azure and mobile services for file upload (encoding after)?

Tags: node.js, model-view-controller, azure

I'm working on an app that needs to upload a wav file and the server needs to covert it to mp3 , modify some tags (using ffmpeg) and store in blob to finally return the url to it.  I'm using Mobile Services for my back end and will use Blob storage to store the converted mp3.

The problem is what will be the best way to do the upload/convert in the cloud?  Should I use a cloud app or VM to deploy the app?  Should I use MVC API to create the endpoint that the app POST the file to and then converts and stores to blob?  Or instead of MVC use Node.JS (in a VM?) with nginx?

What will be the most effective and efficient of way doing so?  Advice will be great as I'm new to cloud computing.

Answer (score 0):

I know you're using Azure, but have you looked at the AWS Elastic Transcoder service?

http://aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/

Not suggesting you move your app to AWS, but instead use it as a good example for how to architect your API on Azure. They've likely thought through several use cases.

In terms of building this on Azure, I would start by trying to build this using Azure Web Sites (instead of a cloud service or your own VM). Here's a good tutorial for building on Azure Web Sites using Node.js: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/nodejs/tutorials/create-a-website-(mac)/

If you end up going this route and want to build this on a public github repo, let me know. Sounds like a fun project to work on.

Comment: Oh wow the Amazon Elastic Transcoder seems perfect for this!  I may go that way for the Audio files and I may do a public repo depending how the project goes.  Is part of an audio microblog app (think vine but for audio)